# Spring JPA repository and QueryDsl how to force left join

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Let's say I have two entities User and Task, each user can have one task.

The issue that I'm facing is if I have one record in the user table whose email starts with `a` and there are no records at all in the task table.

This snippet below will return no records although I would expect users that have mail starting with `a`.

UserRepository in example extends QuerydslPredicateExecutor.

```java
        userRepository.findAll(
            QUser.user.email.startsWith("a")
                .or(QUser.user.task.text.contains("something"))
        )
```

If I check logs, Hibernate is creating cross join with `user.task_id=task.id` as a part of where clauses. This type of join automatically discards users whose mails are starting with `a` if they don't have a task assigned.

Is there a way to force usage of left join instead of a cross join in findAll method of the repository?

I know I can do it by using `JPAQuery` but then I would have to reimplement paging functionality...

```java
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
        query
            .from(QUser.user)
            .leftJoin(QTask.task)
        // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if we can do that since the findAll implementation is generated for us. However we can pass a predicate in the findAll method which will help deal with issue you are encountering.

You can try to do something like this:

```
QUser qUser = QUser.user;
QTask qTask = QTask.task;

JPQL<UserEntity> userJpqlQuery = JPAExpressions.selectFrom(qUser)
                                         .leftjoin(qUser.task, qTask)
                                         .where(qUser.email...., qTask.text...);


userRepository.findAll(qUser.in(userJpqlQuery));
```

In the code above I have used *Querydsl*, which is an alternative to *CriteriaBuilder* and is type safe. Then I have created a subquery to make the selection I want and return the all users matching the subquery.

In the end , hibernate should generate something like this:

```
select * from User qUser0 where qUser0.id.in( 
              select qUser1.id from User qUser1 
              left join Task qTask0 on 
              qUser1.taskId = qTask0.id 
              where ...
              );
```